# Django Rest Framework APIClient not handling exceptions during tests

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I'm testing an API endpoint that is supposed to raise a ValidationError in a Django model (note that the exception is a Django exception, not DRF, because it's in the model).

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class TestMyView(APITestCase):
    # ...
    def test_bad_request(self):
        # ...
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However, my test errors out with an exception instead of passing. It doesn't even fail getting a 500 instead of 400, it doesn't get there at all. Isn't DRF's APIClient supposed to handle *every* exception? I've search online but found nothing. I've read that DRF doesn't handle Django's native ValidationError, but still that doesn't explain why I am not even getting a 500. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Full stack trace**:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_cannot_create_duplicate_email (organizations.api.tests.test_contacts.TestContactListCreateView)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/organizations/api/tests/test_contacts.py", line 98, in test_cannot_create_duplicate_email
    response = self.jsonapi_post(self.url(new_partnership), data)
  File "/code/config/tests/base.py", line 166, in jsonapi_post
    url, data=json.dumps(data), content_type=content_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 300, in post
    path, data=data, format=format, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 213, in post
    return self.generic('POST', path, data, content_type, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 238, in generic
    method, path, data, content_type, secure, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 422, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 289, in request
    return super(APIClient, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 241, in request
    request = super(APIRequestFactory, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 503, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 244, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 26, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/code/organizations/api/serializers.py", line 441, in create
    'partnership': self.context['partnership']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 943, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/code/organizations/models.py", line 278, in save
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1203, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'__all__': ['Supplier contact emails must be unique per organization.']}
```

Comment: i don't understand "it gets a 500" and then "I am not even getting a 500", that seems contradictory. Nor do I understand "it doesn't even get there", get where? Please describe in detail what you get in your console and if there's an error trace, what the error trace is.

Comment: @dirkgroten I edited the question, hope it's clearer now. The bottom line is: I don't get a 500. If I got one, I could debug the reason why DRF is not properly handling the 400, but I'm not getting any response at all.

Comment: Can you show the full error trace that you get in your test console?

Comment: @dirkgroten I've edited the question and edited the stack trace.

Comment: added an important edit. raise the DRF's own `ValidationError` inside your save method and all will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**: Isn't DRF's APIClient supposed to handle every exception?

**Answer**: No. It's a test client, it won't handle any uncaught exceptions, that's how test clients work. Test clients propagate the exception so that the test fails with a "crash" when an exception isn't caught. You can test that exceptions are raised and uncaught with [`self.assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)

**Question**: The APIView should return HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST when I raise a ValidationError but the exception isn't caught.

**Answer**:

You should look at the [source code for APIView](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.views/APIView.html#handle_exception).

Inside the `dispatch()` method, all exceptions raised while creating the `response` object are caught and the method `handle_exception()` is called.

Your exception is a `ValidationError`. The crucial lines are:

```
exception_handler = self.get_exception_handler()
context = self.get_exception_handler_context()
response = exception_handler(exc, context)
if response is None:
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
```

If you haven't changed `settings.EXCEPTION_HANDLER`, you get the default DRF exception handler, [source code here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.0/rest_framework/views.py#L73).

If handles `Http404`, `PermissionDenied` and `APIException`. The `APIView` itself actually also handles `AuthenticationFailed` and `NotAuthenticated`. But not `ValidationError`. So it returns `None` and therefore the view raises your `ValidationError` which stops your test.

You see that in your traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
```

You can decide to handle more exceptions than the default ones handled by DRF, you can read [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) on custom exception handling.

**EDIT**: You can also `raise rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError` instead of the standard Django `ValidationError`. That is an `APIException` and therefore will be handled by DRF as a `HTTP400_BAD_REQUEST`. [1]

Side note: Luckily DRF doesn't catch every single exception! If there's a serious flaw in your code you actually **want** your code to "crash" and produce an error log and your server to return a HTTP 500. Which is what happens here. The response would be an HTTP 500 if this wasn't the test client.

[1]https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.9.0/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L142

Comment: I wouldn't expect DRF to catch every single exception, I agree that in some cases you do want the code to crash. So it makes sense that APIView doesn't catch everything. But I certainly did expect the APIClient to handle all exceptions. How can it even be called a client if it doesn't? If the FE calls that endpoint and gets a 500, the APIClient should get the same.

Comment: It does return a http 500 if you run it on your server and fetch the url with a browser client. In the test client, uncaught exceptions aren't returned in the response but are raised so you can debug your tests. Otherwise you wouldn't have any information about the exception!

Comment: sorry, I did indeed confuse `APIClient` with `APIView` in my answer. Corrected above.

Comment: Is there a way to use something similar to APIClient, but where you would get an actual response analogous to the http response? To my mind, if I'm testing an API, I want to look for a HTTP 400, not catch a validation error; otherwise, it's not a proper API test.

Comment: @KenKinder I don’t understand your question. If your view returns a HTTP 400 error page when a validation error is raised, then the APIClient will indeed see a HTTP response with status 400 and you will be able to assert that’s the case. The above question from OP was a case where an error is raised within the view *that isn’t handled*, ie doesn’t cause a status 400 page to be returned.

Comment: @dirkgroten For example, a ValidationError is handled by DRF/internally by Django. If I'm testing a view, I want to make sure a view returns a 400/bad request. However, since that response is generated by Django code, it isn't part of the view itself, so an exception is raise. If the test catches exceptions that are caught by Django, it's not a test of the API; it's only a test of the view function itself.

Comment: @KenKinder what you're saying doesn't make sense: If your view returns a 400 bad request, then the `APIClient` will also see a 400 bad request error and test your API correctly. Only *uncaught* exceptions (which *always* return a 500 error in the end) cannot be tested as 500 errors, but are raised through into your testing code. A `ValidationError` is *not* handled by DRF/Django if it's raised in view. **You have to catch it in your view** and if you do, then you can also test that with the `APIClient`.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for bearing with me. I actually created a small test project to prove you wrong, but in my test project, it is indeed working as expected. Something weird must be going on with our middleware; sorry to run you around in circles on this.

Comment: @KenKinder you won’t prove me wrong :-) if your view is returning a 400/bad request HTTP response, you can `assert` that in your test. If your view is just raising an exception, you won’t get to the response in your test client but the exception will “bubble up” to your test.

Comment: "that's how test clients work"... Source? How am I supposed to do negative testing if the framework does its very best to change the behaviour at testing time compared to what would happen in the real world? I'm used to test clients which behave like clients, and get a response back when something goes wrong, not just when it goes right. That's how clients work.

Comment: I should have said "that's how a *unit* test client works". The idea of unit tests is to catch exceptions and enable you to debug them. A 500 error is always a "crash" so the reason Django's test client raises the exception is to help you in your work as developer. 
If you want to test a real world scenario end-to-end, write a functional test using something like Selenium or Playwright.
Note that since Django v3.0 you can actually suppress these exceptions and explicitly ask the test client to not raise the exceptions but return what it would return normally.

Comment: Also I need to stress again: All your negative test cases should be handled. There should *never* be a case where you wittingly return a 500 error. So normally, you never have a test case where you *expect* a HTTP 5xx response. Any negative test case, i.e. something goes wrong and you expect it to go wrong in that case, should be handled and return a known HTTP status (like 4xx).

Answer (score 1):

## Django >3.0

Starting with Django 3.0, `Client` constructor takes `raise_request_exception` parameter. Set it `False` and response 500 will returned instead of raising an exception.

Source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.0/#tests

```py
self.client = Client(raise_request_exception=False)
```

## Django <3.0

There is a workaround for this for Django 2.2 and earlier.

**TL;DR:**

Just mock the `store_exc_info` method of `Client` class.

```py
from unittest import mock

class TestMyView(APITestCase):
    ...
    def test_server_error(self):
        mock.patch("django.test.client.Client.store_exc_info")
        self.client.post("/url/, data)
        ...
```

Now, the client will return regular response object with status code = 500.

**Explanation:**

Django's Test client always raises exceptions, even if they were wrapped in 500 Server error response.

`Client` connects its method called `store_exc_info` to the `got_request_exception` Django's signal (source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.2.5/django/test/client.py#L712)

```py
got_request_exception.connect(self.store_exc_info, dispatch_uid=exception_uid)
```

This method saves an exception info as `self.exc_info`. This attribute is later tested if its `None`. If it is, then error is raised. If not, response is normally returned (source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.24/django/test/client.py#L500)

Mocking the `self.store_exc_info` makes it do nothing, so exception info is not stored - therefore it's `None` later :)

Answer (score 0):

Something in your code is causing a python error which is halting execution before your POST request can return a valid HTTP response. Your code doesn't even reach the line `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)` because there is no response.

If you're calling your tests in the normal way with `./manage.py test` then you should see the traceback and be able to narrow down what caused the error.

Comment: But in the traceback the error that is raised is exactly the error that I want to test. Namely, a Django ValidationError in a model's `save` method.